# Oracle (?) DB dump file

Tags: database, oracle

I have a legacy DB dump file which starts off something like this:

```
^C^@&D
EXPORT:V07.03.04
DHISTO
RTABLES
8192
0
^@    Mon Jan 11 09:02:31 2010
TABLE "ABCD"
CREATE TABLE "ABCD" ("TIME" DATE, "ELEMENT" CHAR(16), ....
```

From the "EXPORT:V07.03.04", and from the data I do have, I am assuming this is an Oracle DB dump (v7). Which tools do I have available to import this data?

---

Thanks everybody for the help. I ended up installing Oracle XE 10g, and using it to import the dump files - worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it looks like an Oracle dump format. You can use the imp command:

```
imp userid=user/passwd file=file.dmp ignore=y
```

Use ignore=y to skip tables that already exist (imp will give an error if the object is re-created). Depending on what you whant to import from the dump you may also have to use other flags, such as full=y (Grants and constraints are automatically included).

See

```
imp help=yes
```

for all options of this command.

Comment: Thanks! On a machine which currently has no Oracle installation, what would be the fastest way to import this data so I can export it to other formats and work with it?

Comment: Maybe you could download a preconfigured virtual machine or use a respective instance of a cloud provider. Then again it probably isn't too time consuming to install a version of Oracle XE (free) on your local computer. Then fire up imp with your data.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle [`imp`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/original_import.htm#i1023560) is the counterpart to [`exp`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/original_export.htm#BABBHCIE) which created this file.

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ

Answer (score 2):

> "On a machine which currently has no
>   Oracle installation, what would be the
>   fastest way to import this data so I
>   can export it to other formats and
>   work with it?"

The file is an Oracle proprietary format.  So the easiest way of working with it would be to install an Oracle database and use IMP to load it.  You can use pretty much any version of Oracle as the target because IMP has backwards compatibility going way back.  If you have an Oracle Support account the relevant note is id=132904.1 .

Comment: Would Oracle Express Edition 11g be able to handle this v7 format?

Comment: @YuvalA - 10gR2 is the only available version of XE.  XE does support IMP.  Note that the XE documentation gives examples using Datapump Import - that won't work with an Oracle7 Export file: you need to use the Import utility.

Comment: so just to clarify - using `imp` should work with oracle7 dump file?

Answer (score 1):

Try "imp": http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Oracle+export+and+import+